# Force User to uninstall previous version manually before installing new one : WIX

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.7

I have installer generated by WiX and I want it to tell: "Please Uninstall the previous version before installing newerone ?" when running the installer if the previous version is already installed.And setup should only proceed if all the previous version are uninstalled.

How to do ths in Wix project..?/

Comment: Would it not be a better user experience if you performed the uninstall automatically (after a suitable prompt) rather than turn the computer into a tool that tries to control the users actions?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever before i tried autoUninstall in wix using  RemoveExsistingProducts but in windows 8.1 it has some administrator issues.So only am asking useritself to uninstall

Comment: You may need to clarify that question. You want to run the upgrade and tell the user to uninstall the previous version, ok. But then you say setup should only work if previous versions are already installed, which means if no previous versions are on the system you don't want setup to run. Do you mean "already uninstalled"? Also, why not have a question about the administrator issues to see if that can be solved? All Windows Installer upgrades by default will uninstall the older version and install the new one - that's the expected user experience.

Comment: I think if you follow the guideline of [Test upgrade scenarios before you ship version 1](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html), you'll find that you won't be able to validate this requirement (that is, you don't need it).